# Generating usage logs that prove my Internet connection is flaky

Tags: internet, display, connection

I need a way to generate reports or logs that prove that my Internet connection is flaky. My Comcast connection is very flaky but if I ask their support to send someone over it will probably work fine while the guy is here.

I found and tried "Connection Monitor" from CSGWare Corp but it does not create the kind of reports or graphs I'd need to be able to convince my ISP that their link is intermittent.

What I need to be able to do is have the software monitor my connection and produce a record of when the connection dies or when, for example, ping time climbs dramatically.

Can I get Connection Monitor to do this or is there another program that does?

Comment: What OS?  Is it a direct connect from computer to whatever you use as a connection?  Giving more details will help people trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have known enough to do that.

I'm in Windows XP Pro and it is a connection through my router to a cable modem.

Comment: If your connection is dropping off intermittently they'll be able to tell on their side if it's their problem. It might be dropping off locally. Prove it's their problem first

Comment: Jay, while running whatever tool you choose, make sure your computer is connected directly to the cable modem or results won't count for anything.

Comment: I'd try to describe the problem more precisely than: "My Comcast connection is very flaky" Does the connection go away altogether? Assuming that there's some kind of "Connected" indicator LED on your modem, does it stay lit or not? Is there a pattern to when it comes and goes? Or is it that you appear to have connectivity but you can't seem to connect to anything ... web sites, mail servers and the like? In that case, next time it's working right, look up the IP address for a site, then next time the service seems to be out, try connecting to the IP address rather than the www.whatever.xyz add

Comment: There are scripts online that you can use to generate a small script that will continuously, every five minutes or whatever you specify, ping a specified IP address and write the results to a log file. I added tracert. The $10 program mentioned [in Dave's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/38666/generating-usage-logs-that-prove-my-internet-connection-is-flaky/351908#351908) is one of a number of such utilities that pretty much does the same thing.

Answer (score 34):

Bash script, with timestamp, so when you show it to Comcast, you can point to exact times when it was down or flaky.

```
ping comcast.net | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done > ~/log.txt
```

...produces output like this:

```
Thu Jun  5 00:23:54 CDT 2014: 64 bytes from 0.0.0.0: icmp_seq=235 ttl=55 time=61.848 ms
Thu Jun  5 00:23:55 CDT 2014: Request timeout for icmp_seq 236
Thu Jun  5 00:23:56 CDT 2014: 64 bytes from 0.0.0.0: icmp_seq=236 ttl=55 time=1317.795
```

Then, you can monitor it in a different window with `tail`

```
tail -f ~/log.txt
```

Clear and concise.  Works for Mac and Linux.  Not sure about Windows.

Comment: My Windows 10 results:                                            
`C:\Users\Michael\My Documents>ping comcast.net | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done` resulted in
`'while' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Michael yeah, `while` is a unix command.  You might be able to get something similar working with a little work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1788473/652626

Comment: WSL will allow you to do this on Windows 10 (Windows Subsystem for Linux is a compatibility layer for running Linux binary executables natively on Windows 10)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: used this twice and logged in two files: 1. to ping my proxy and check if my VPN is working and 2. to ping a website directly to check if VPN is lost due to a broken internet connection.

Answer (score 19):

```
ping -t comcast.net > log.txt
```

Show them the `log.txt` file.

Comment: Sorry but that went over my head.  Are you saying to use the Dos window to issue a ping command or are you saying there is a log.txt file out there that I can open and read and offer as proof?

Thanks

Comment: Jay: Type that command into a DOS / Shell prompt. When he shows up, use ctrl-c to abort it.  It will generate a file called log.txt which will show the ping results. The log.txt file will appear in the directory your DOS prompt was started in.

Comment: Just remember to hook that specific computer directly to the Internet, otherwise he may say it's your router

Comment: @shufler: not for mac: ping: invalid timeout: `google.com'

Comment: For Mac (and probably all Unix-based systems), drop the -t switch. Not sure what it does under Windows, but it makes Unix ping interpret "comcast.net" as a timeout period (between pings).

Comment: For Windows `ping`, the `-t` switch has it ping continuously until interrupted (the default is to break after 4 requests).

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem with a Comcast connection that lasted three years - dozens of dropouts every day.  Finally I wrote a program that continuously tests an internet connection and writes a  log of any outages.  I showed Comcast the logs and they finally took me seriously and fixed it!

I'm selling the program (free trial, $10 for a license) to help others resolve their problems with their ISP.  It's called Net Uptime Monitor - http://www.netuptimemonitor.com.  It's a simple program that does exactly what you want - continuously monitors your internet connection and writes a plain text log of every failure that occurs, including the start time and length of the outage.

There's no complicated configuration or anything - it's really a single purpose program, just install it and run it.  The logs it generates will help your ISP figure out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple tool which checks if it can access an internet site and logs results with time stamps. It is written in Java and will work on any platform.
http://code.google.com/p/internetconnectivitymonitor/

Comment: It doesn't log response time, if the connection drops for tens of seconds you won't notice it.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [DUMeter](http://www.dumeter.com/download.php). There's a 30 day trial version available. 
Or use [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) and let it monitor the availability of your IP address, given that you have a (sort of) fixed IP. Pingdom has a free plan. I'm using Pingdom myself for a number of websites and it proved to be very helpful.

Comment: I'm running Pingdom now - beginning to receive results from it.  Might be a big help.  Thanks for the lead.

Comment: DUMeter does not report ping times or connectivity issues. It reports bandwidth usage only. It is not suitable for the OPs use-case.

Answer (score 3):

Complain to a Consumer Protection authority.
Let **them** monitor it.

Complaining to an ISP and showing it a ping log file?
Come on, guys, you must be kidding.
How would you prove the authenticity of a simple text file? How would you prove you didn't write it up yourself?

If you want to monitor your connection, you can set up [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/). You can even point your ISP to it. But I doubt that'll help. If your provider doesn't treat you fair as a consumer, just quit using its services if you have alternatives.

Comment: It may not prove that the connection is dropping to them, but it will give them an exact time to check their logs which will make them more likely to actually check them compared to if they have to hunt through their logs looking for an "uh... my connection keeps dropping".

Comment: Your average consumer protection agency likely already monitors Comcast, and surely won't setup a custom rig just for your connection.  So it's mostly useless to bother them.
Besides, as I understand it, this is not for proof in a legal sense, but to provide a tech with help in troubleshooting.
A lot of us don't have any option except Comcast, so we use what tools we're able.

Answer (score 3):

[SmokePing](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) provides long-term storage and visualization for various tests including latency and packet loss.  Perhaps it would be useful for UNIX/Linux users.

Answer (score 1):

My cable modem for Time Warner is accessible at a particular address 192.168.xxx.yyy similar to the way a home router is.  If I point my browser to that address there is an interface that allows me to see some diagnostic pages including a log of recent activity.

If your connection is dying, it may be that the log will show something that happened at that time.  Mine did when I was having a problem: lots of "timeout" and "re-establishing DHCP connection" messages.

Find out the make and model of your cable modem and then try a web search to find out how to access the configurations screens.

I suspect that any cable repair person will check those logs anyway.  If there's a discrepancy between the cable modem log and the logs you get from a third-party app, who will they believe?

Comment: Both of the Comcast boxes I had responded on 192.168.100.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to generate a few different log files to a few different sites.

```
tracert -d comcast.net > log.txt
```

this will generate a traceroute and you/they can identify if the flakiness is local to you, on their network, or the backbone network.

Comcast is probably unaware of your service issue. Provided you find a decent contact with their support, they might be able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an older question, but I found it searching for a solution, so I ended up writing one. It's a shell script that checks for internet connectivity, and logs any outages, along with the reconnected link speed. I made it for this exact issue. Feel free to grab it: https://github.com/TristanBrotherton/netcheck

[image: netcheck]

Answer (score 0):

To complete the very good solution of @allanberry you can just use the `tee` command to display the result while writing to the file

```
ping comcast.net | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done | tee ~/log.txt
```