# Tool or utility for automatically checking internet speeds

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth

My workplace is deciding whether to switch ISPs, so I have been tasked with checking our internet connection speeds twice a day (once at 2pm, once at 2am).

I am wondering if there was a utility that I could download and run that would do this automatically in the background over the next couple of weeks, and give me a CSV of the results.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is off-topic because it is asking for a product recommendation. Many people don't realize there is a list of what is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for this site. You can take a *[tour]* and read *[ask]* to learn more about how this site works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically collect internet (broadband) speed metrics over time](http://superuser.com/questions/388809/automatically-collect-internet-broadband-speed-metrics-over-time), and/or [Generating usage logs that prove my Internet connection is flaky](http://superuser.com/questions/38666/generating-usage-logs-that-prove-my-internet-connection-is-flaky)

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool in python, which test via speedtest.net:

https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

If you are using linux you could write a small bash script and run it with a cron job.