# Log internet connection outages in windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10

My internet connection seems to drop out a lot at certain times of the day. I've been looking for a way to capture how often this happens. I'm aware of tools but they are either not free or dont really capture the type of data im after e.g. outages vs uptime over a week so.

I've noticed that Windows 10 displays "No Internet, secured" when there is no connection. Is it possible to get windows to log this somwhere so i can then workout Internet up vs down time.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the event log (if any) for network failure?](http://superuser.com/questions/1031263/how-to-check-the-event-log-if-any-for-network-failure)

Answer (score 14):

The event viewer will register a log every time the internet connects and disconnects. You can access this log in the Event Viewer by navigating to -

Applications And Services Logs / Microsoft / Windows / UniversalTelemetryClient

and then look for every instance of Event 55. In the General tab it will show "Is the Internet available: false" every time the internet drops.

Comment: the event log is delayed for about 1-2 mins than the actual event. this means shorter intermittent failures did not show up in this log (this is in my case). however for longer down time (> 2 mins), this is really good!.

Comment: In my case, the connection losses are less than a few seconds. Any idea how I could track those?

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/763823/1176155) for a method that can check for short disconnects.