# Log uptime/downtime, win10

Tags: windows-10, networking, logging, wan, uptime

I'm currently having a issue with my WAN, my LAN never goes down but my WAN seems to lose connection every 30minutes (roughly). I'm wondering if there is a way to log the times automatically like maybe a ping with a delay and verbose log to a text document or something.  Away from home ATM as well and need to track the uptime and downtime as my ISP is investigating the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906268/ping-with-timestamp-on-windows-cli

Comment: Check [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1169395/log-internet-connection-outages-in-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware windows logged it automatically.