# Get macOS ping to only log timeouts

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, ping

I have a similar case to: [Generating usage logs that prove my Internet connection is flaky](https://superuser.com/questions/38666/generating-usage-logs-that-prove-my-internet-connection-is-flaky)

However these logs will get long quickly. I am only interested in logging timeouts, is there a way to achieve this? I was hoping `-q` might but it doesn't seem to.

I am doing this on macOS, so I'm looking for a solution that works with macOS's BSD-derived `ping(8)` (https://ss64.com/mac/ping.html)

I would like to search the strings *after* they are processed (in this case prefixed) so I can have more flexibility:

```
ping comcast.net | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done
```

I know `ping comcast.net grep timeout` will *almost* work, but I can't figure out how to combine `grep` into my existing script

Comment: Does `ping host | grep timeout` accomplish what you want?

Comment: @Spiff almost/probably but I can't figure out how to combine it, see edits.